# Is EKU filtering possible on IIS/http.sys

Tags: iis, http.sys

Is it possible to filter client certificates in the browser using EKU (Extended Key Usage) detail of a certificate? I only want certificates that have Client Authentication EKU, or no EKUs at all.

I know this happens by setting oid_filters in the CertificateRequest message in tls handshake, but I don't know how to set them, or if there's an easier configuration in IIS/http.sys to do this?

Comment: You do know that "client certificates" = "certificates that have Client Authentication EKU, or no EKUs at all", right? So there is no room for you to do any extra filtering on server side. The browsers take that responsibilities and they do very well.

Comment: @LexLi You might be right, I made a mistake about what's my requirement. Certificates I'm interested in come in pairs on a token, one for for signing and one for identification, and I actually need to filter out those for signing, which don't have EKU. Any advise?

Comment: IIS only has a pass/fail gate that works during normal SSL/TLS handshakes, that rejects invalid certificates and reports back 403.7 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code#403---forbidden. So if you have some other certificate sent to IIS, it simply won't work. You can only get through when a valid client certificate is present.